# Partition issue

Tags: partitioning

I had Windows 10 and wanted to switch to ubuntu. I've created a boot usb, put it on my laptop, restarted. Then I selected to erase everything and install.

The problem is I loose my boot partition. Currently my partitions are a mess. i've tryed to install ubuntu several times. No success. Keep saying "Checking media presence, No media Present". My laptop only boots if I put USB pen on it.

How to hard reset it? Or what partitions should I setup in order to system work fine?

Comment: During installation you can choose where you want to install the bootloader. Check if the correct driver / partition is selected.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCvx.png

Comment: Some information that might help people figure out what is wrong:

what model of laptop? i.e. "Dell Inspiron 15 from 2015"

did the installation finish successfully?  i.e. it installed ok but now won't boot

is your laptop setup to boot using  UEFI?  See also here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: My laptop model ia a Toshiba Satellite L50 - A - 1CU. The installation finished successfully, it ask me to restart, I removed usb pen, click restart and then... when system boots I got the error  "Checking media presence, No media Present".

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from an Ubuntu "live disk." This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. That will give us detailed technical information on your current configuration and enable an answer based on more than guesswork and assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is an important step while setting up any OS, specially linux base OS like ubuntu.
 Please refer a detailed video which I sure will solve all your problems:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8BkXgVx7mE

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.